# iTunes 12.5.1.21 interface with iPod Classic (2009) software 2.0.4 Star vs Heart Rating

Tags: itunes, ipod, ratings

I cannot get the Star Rating System to work through iTunes as it displays on my iPod.

I can get the iTunes to display the Star ratings for music on my Macbook Pro. It was easy enough to go into Preferences > General > [Check Box] Star Ratings.

I don't use the Heart system on the iPod itself. It's always Star (which I prefer, as I employ a gradient rating for the music).

How can I get iTunes to display the Star rating system for the music on my iPod and not just what is stored locally?

Answer (score 1):

In your preferred playlist chose to display it as a list (song view) and right click on one of the top columns (artist, album, year, etc.) and select 'rating' from the menu.

It may be only visible if you scroll the list view to the right. You can reorder the columns by holding and dragging with the mouse.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. The rating shows, but it shows the HEART option instead of the stars. Which is odd, because on the iPod itself, it only shows the stars option.  Not certain why the difference.....

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant. It works brother!!

Comment: @Aaron awesome – I'm glad it works as you wanted it to work!